# Convert Inputs to Text in Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

So I am looping through the html of a table like so:

```
jQuery('#result_'+formId+' tr').each(function() {
        pHtml += '<tr>';
        pHtml += jQuery(this).html();
        pHtml += '</tr>';
    });
```

and if I console.log this it returns:

```
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><label for="CashTotal_8">Cash Total:</label></td>
      <td><label for="AverageRate_8">Average Rate:</label></td>
      <td><label for="CashMonthTotal_8">Cash Per Month Total:</label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><label>Total:</label></td>
      <td><input class="form-control validate-num" id="CashTotal_8" placeholder="0.00" disabled="disabled" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control validate-num" id="AverageRate_8" placeholder="0.00" disabled="disabled" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control validate-num" id="CashMonthTotal_8" placeholder="0.00" disabled="disabled" type="text"></td>
   </tr>
```

which is perfect but I need to some how replace all the inputs with there current values.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Do you want it replaced in the document or just inside html content of`pHtml`?

Comment: just the pHtml would be fantastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the table html with inputs replaced with their value, try something like,

```
var pHtml=$('#result_'+formId).clone().find("input").replaceWith(function()
      {
          return $("<span></span>").text($(this).val()); 
      }).end().html();
```

or in case you want to build the `tr` manually with your code,

```
jQuery('table tr').each(function() {
    pHtml += '<tr>';
    pHtml += jQuery(this).clone()
                         .find("input")
                         .replaceWith(function(){
                                                  return $(this).val();
                                                }).end().html();
    pHtml += '</tr>';
});
```

or in case you want it replaced in the document, go with this,

```
$('#result_'+formId+' input').replaceWith(function()
       {
            return $("<span></span>").text($(this).val()); 
       });
```

Above code assumes `'#result_'+formId` is the id of `<table>`

Comment: Beautiful Thanks, Didn't use you code exactly but it was but it was the base of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#result_'+formId+' tr').each(function() {

    $(this).children('td').each(function(){

        if($(this).children('input').length>0){

            var value=$(this).children('input').val();
            $(this).empty().html(value)
        }
    })
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vNDbX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Is the `<input>` always the only thing in the `<td>`?  If so, you can just set the HTML of the parent of the `<input>` (that being the `<td>`) as the value of the `<input>`.  Something like this:

```
$("input").each(function () {
  $(this).parent().html($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the find function is what you are looking for:

```
jQuery('#result_'+formId+' tr').each(function() {
        pHtml += '<tr>';
        var child = jquery(this).find('input');
        if (child.val()) {
            var current = child.html();
            var newText = jQuery(this).html().replace(current, child.val()); 
            pHtml += newText;
        }
        else {
            pHtml += jQuery(this).html();
        }
        pHtml += '</tr>';
    });
```